# keep image in update form

Tags: php, image

My update form is not fully working.

These are in my form.

```
<tr><td>Afbeelding : </td><td><?php echo "<img src='upload/".$row['img']."' />"; ?><?php echo $row['img']?></tr>
<tr><td></td><td> <input type="file" name="img" accept="image/jpg,image/gif,image/png" /></tr></td>
```

if name="img" is empty, the form should keep the image from the line above

can someone help me with this (I am a beginner)

Full code: (php)

```
<?php                               
error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE);
$id = $_GET['id'];
if($id==""){
echo "Geen nummer ingevuld";
exit;
}

mysql_connect("xxxxxx","xxxx","xxxx") or die("Kan geen verbinding maken met de server!");
mysql_select_db("xxxx") or die("Kan de ingevoerde database niet vinden"); 

if ($_POST){
$query = "UPDATE auteurs SET 
naam = '".$_POST['naam']."',
img = '".$_POST['img']."',
bio = '".$_POST['bio']."'


WHERE
id = $id

";

mysql_query($query) or die("Uitvoeren mislukt!<br>" . mysql_error());

header("location:auteur2.php");
exit;
}

$query = "SELECT naam, img, bio, id from auteurs WHERE id=$id";
$r = mysql_query($query) or die("Uitvoeren query mislukt<br>" . mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($r);

?>
```

Comment: Can you provide full code of update page?

Comment: I added the full php code

Comment: So you can simply dont include img in update process if img was not uploaded or uploaded with errors. `$query = "UPDATE auteurs SET 
naam = '".$_POST['naam']."',

bio = '".$_POST['bio']."'";` and at the end you can write `if($newPhoto) $query .= ", img = '$newPhoto'";`

Comment: You have an incorrect closing `</td>` in your very first code row after the closing first row `</tr>`. ... I already removed it in this code here. But you will have to edit it accordingly in your local file.

Comment: Add fields to update query only if they are not empty.

Comment: @GeorgePHP Now it's updating all the naam's and bio's (all the same value)  but not the image

Comment: You have to do image processing and for example to assign new image name to `$newPhoto` when everything is ok, empty string '' otherwise, before executing the update block

Answer (score 0):

in server side of php, you can check

```
if ($_POST){
    $photo = // get your existing photo

    if ($_FILES['img']['name']!=null || $_FILES['img']['name']!=''){
      $photo =   basename($_FILES['img']['name']);
    }else {
      $photo = // get your existing photo
    }

$query = "UPDATE auteurs SET 
naam = '".$_POST['naam']."',
img = '".$photo."',
bio = '".$_POST['bio']."'


WHERE
id = $id

";
```

Comment: where is your form action goes